# Scrollable screen over dynamic background

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I'm fairly new to Flutter and am trying to accomplish something similar to what is being used in the Pigeon app for iOS. Basically I want an interactive page as a background in the app (like the map in the Pigeon app), and then have different screens appear over that background. These screens should be scrollable, but start at the bottom of the device screen, thus showing both the screen and the dynamic background at the same time. As long as the background is visible in you can interact both with it and the scrollable screen.

I have added a gif below which hopefully helps explaining the issues.

Any guidance on which widgets to look into would be appreciated. I've been experimenting with the Stack widget but can't yet figure out how to accomplish my desired behaviour.

[image]

Comment: you can put you Map() and List() in Stack(children:[]) like  `Stack(children:[Map(),List()])`

Answer (score 1):

For doing this kind of stuff you have to use sliver widget, which is provide by flutter material package
for more info you can check
[Flutter Sliver](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar-class.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Looking into Slivers now and it might be able to help me achieve this.